# Support for AWS VPC with Direct Connect and Internet Gateway is available or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to implement the scenario where AWS VPC I want connectivity to both Direct Connect and IGW, so some application I can access from data center and access aws resources from internet

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can provision an **Internet Gateway** on the VPC to provide direct access to the Internet, and you can also provision a **Virtual Private Gateway** that connects to Direct Connect for connectivity to your on-premises or data center networks.

The Route Table configuration will determine which traffic is routed to each gateway.

If your only need for using an Internet Gateway is to "access aws resources from internet" (rather than making your services public), then you should put your resources in **private subnets** and place a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet. This way, your AWS resources will have outbound Internet connectivity via the NAT Gateway without being exposed to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks John , my requirement is EC2 instance running Jenkins master, , i want  it to to connect with system running in data center connected via direct connect and also another machine running over internet , Main jenkins master should be accessible via internet .

Comment: my requirement is EC2 instance running Jenkins master, , i want it to to connect with system running in data center connected via direct connect and also another machine running over internet , Main jenkins master should be accessible via internet .

Comment: That's fine. Sounds like you'll want to put the master in a public subnet, where it can be reached from the Internet and can also communicate across Direct Connect.